# Strange OLEDB Excel Export Issue

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I've written a program to generate an Excel Workbook in C# using OLEDB. Mostly working, but one thing I've noticed is that if I output only 1 column, it leaves a blank row after the header.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that I'm using, and I'm not seeing the issue.  I'm creating a new workbook/spreadsheet and then populating just one row and column.

Can you post your code and we can see what the differences are?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\SOTest2.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;""";
        DbProviderFactory factory =
          DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

        using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();  //open the connection 

                command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet1] (F1 number);";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();  //create the sheet before doing any inserts 

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1) VALUES(4)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();  //now insert a row into the sheet 
            }
        }
    }
```

I also don't see a blank row if I insert a single row with multiple columns:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet1] (F1 number, F2 char(255), F3 char(128))";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();  //create the sheet before doing any inserts 
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1, F2, F3) VALUES(4,\"Tampa\",\"Florida\")";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();  //now insert a row into the sheet
```

Hope this helps!